# HP Stream 8 tablet... Java swing JScrollPane scrolling not working on touch

Tags: java, windows, swing, tablet

I have to following code..

```
final JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
layeredPane.setLayout(new MaximumLayout());
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
layeredPane.setLayer(scrollPane, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
layeredPane.add(scrollPane);
```

The scrolling is working using mouse wheel in the Desktop and laptop.

But When I put my swing application in HP Stream 8 Tablet, the scrolling is not working using finger touch. I don't know why ??

Any suggestions on this ??

Comment: any suggestions on this ??